# Filter out a specific string in a larger string?

Tags: python, string, filtering

I'm new to Python and after this one script I probably won't work with Python at all. I'm extracting some data using Scrapy and have to filter out some string (I've already done this with digits using isdigit()). Googling gives me pages about filtering out special strings, but what I want is really just a small part of a larger string.

This is the string:

```
Nima Python: how are you?
```

What I want left:

```
how are you?
```

so this part removed:

```
Nima Python:
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> s = "Nima Python: how are you?"
>>> s.replace("Nima Python: ", "") # replace with empty string to remove
'how are you?'
```

Comment: The [python manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-functions) says string.replace is deprecated.  Is there a non-deprecated way of doing this?

Comment: @ChrisDodd `string.replace` is deprecated. That is, the function `replace` found in the module `string`. The built-in method `replace` of `str` objects is a different function, and is not deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming there will be other strings like this... so I'm guessing [str.split()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) might be a good bet.

```
>>> string = "Nima Python: how are you (ie: what's wrong)?"
>>> string.split(': ')
['Nima Python', 'how are you (ie', " what's wrong)?"]
>>> string.split(': ', 1)[1]
"how are you (ie: what's wrong)?"
```

Comment: string = "Nima Python: Not so well.  Everyone seems to be forgetting that 'Nima Python: ' or ': ' might occur as a substring on the right, but that's okay.  split and replace both take an argument counting the number of times to split/replace."

Comment: This is why you use `partition()`.

Comment: @DSM: You're absolutely right. I should have used _maxsplit_.

Answer (score 3):

String slicing: (This is the easiest way, but isn't very flexible)

```
>>> string = "Nima Python: how are you?"
>>> string
'Nima Python: how are you?'
>>> string[13:] # Used 13 because we want the string from the 13th character
'how are you?'
```

String replace:

```
>>> string = "Nima Python: how are you?"
>>> string.replace("Nima Python: ", "")
'how are you?'
```

String split: (splitting the string into two parts using the ":")

```
>>> string = "Nima Python: how are you?"
>>> string.split(":")[1].strip()
'how are you?'
```

Comment: and how do you get number `13`?

Comment: Just counted the position of the start of "how" in the string. Not a clever way, I agree.

Comment: @neizod: Try the `Spring split` solution. It is more generic.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> string = 'Nima Python: how are you?'
>>> string.split(':')[1].strip()
'how are you?'
```